# Is it bad practice to put elements below the </body></html> tags?

Tags: html, partials, hogan.js

Sure the following looks stupid:

```
<!--partialPage.html-->
<html>
    <head>A css file linked here...</head>
    <body>
        First piece of content
    </body>
</html>

blah after html
```

...and could easily be fixed by moving the `blah after html` into the body. Turns out the browser does that for you, and appends this to the end of the body. (Not a good reason to do this stupid thing)

I did however find a good reason why I would want to do this that would simplify partial layouts in template engines.

```
<!--page1.html-->
{{> partialPage}}                        <!--This is a partial/include-->
Content that would later be teleported into the body.

<!--page2.html-->
{{> partialPage}}                        <!--This is a partial/include-->
Another page using the layout
```

This is of course simpler than doing all of the following:

```
//sendPartials.js
{
    partialOne: 'Content that would later be teleported into the body',
    partialTwo: 'Another page using the layout'
}

<!--page1.html-->
<html>
    <head>A css file linked here...</head>
    <body>
        First piece of content
        {{> partialOne}}
    </body>
</html>


<!--page2.html-->
<html>
    <head>A css file linked here...</head>
    <body>
        First piece of content
        {{> partialTwo}}
    </body>
</html>
```

So the questions comes down to... Which method should I be using?

Is it bad to create a partial that IS the layout file?

Comment: Not true buddy. Try to open up the original partialPage.html in your browser

Comment: create a template or use php if you are adding multiple files with the same structure

Comment: What I'm trying to figure out is: Would it be a good idea to create a template as a partial and save time, or to create content partials for each page(which would require each page to hold the boring html/head/script stuff).

Comment: @MaxMastalerz _Turns out the browser does that for you, and appends this to the end of the body_ - I wouldn't be sure that all browsers do that.

Comment: Good thought to consider. This feature wasn't listed in any html spec I've seen. I discovered it through a wtf moment when viewing the yanexbo boilerplate The `extends layout` line https://github.com/atufkas/yanexbo/blob/master/views/index.jade

Answer (score 1):

Just because a browser will let you get away with something doesn't mean you should take advantage of it. Some potential caveats:

- This might not work in every browser.
- This might work in every browser now, but not in six months.
- This might work in every browser, but with subtle differences you might not catch.
- This might make the browser turn on [quirks mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) or some similar mode. You really don't want your pages rendering in quirks mode, because it can cause lots of random and minor things to work subtly differently. You could be working on some completely unrelated feature six months down the line, and have an issue where the browser isn't doing what you'd expect, solely because it's running in quirks mode.

I'd say this is like putting a credit card through a paper shredder -- sure, it might get the job done, but it's really not a good practice to rely upon.

Comment: Have you checked this in the spec? Html built was around helping noobies. The markup is very forgiving. So forgiving that even the html/body/head tags are optional.

Comment: Yes, HTML is meant to be usable by noobs and browsers are meant to do their best to parse awful HTML. But just because that safety net is there doesn't mean you should lean on it if you want to write code that does and always will run correctly in every browser.

Comment: I recommend sticking to the [principle of robustness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle): "Be conservative in what you send, be liberal in what you accept". Browsers are liberal in what they accept, but you should still be conservative in what you send.